# Image width and height not sizing as I specified

Tags: php, css

All,
I have the following code to display an image on my page:

```
$output .= '<div id="bd-flickr">';
    for($i=0; $i<$count_photos; $i++){
        if($xml->channel->item[$i]){
                preg_match( $regx, $xml->channel->item[$i]->description, $matches );
                $img_url = str_replace("_m.jpg", "_z.jpg", $matches[1]);
                $output .= '<div class="bd-flickr-item">';
                $output .= '<a rel="flickr-widget" class="fancybox" title="&lt;a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;'.$xml->channel->item[$i]->link.'&quot;&gt;View in Flickr&lt;/a&gt;" href="' . $img_url .'">';
                $output .= '<img src="'.$img_url.'" height="192px" width="192px" alt="'. $xml->channel->item[$i]->title .'" title="'. $xml->channel->item[$i]->title .'">';
                $output .= '</a>';
                $output .= '</div>';
        }
    }
    $output .= '</div><div style="clear:both; float:none"></div>';
    echo $output
```

I'm trying to specify that I want the image width and height to be 192px X 192px and I thought by specifying it that would be acheived. The images being displayed on different heights though. I do have some CSS that came with the theme and here is the CSS:

```
#bd-flickr {min-height:270px}

.bd-flickr-item {
    width:20%;  
    height:auto;  
    float:left; 
    margin:0!important;
    padding:0!important
}

.bd-flickr-item img{
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
    width:100%; 
    height:auto; 
    margin:0!important;
    padding:0!important; 
    display:block
}

html .bd-flickr-item img{
    box-shadow:none!important;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none!important;
    -moz-box-shadow:none!important;
    -o-box-shadow:none!important;
}

.bd-flickr-item img:hover{
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
}

a.bd-flickr-link {
    background:#000000 url(../img/camera.png) no-repeat center center; 
    display:block
}
```

Can anyone see why my images wouldn't be 192px X 192px?

Thanks

Comment: Since no one can run your code: what are you seeing instead?

Comment: you don't need the px in the width and height attributes on an image tag

Comment: The heights of the images are different. So one image is 192pxX128px and then another one is 192pxX288px and they just keep varying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:

```
.bd-flickr-item img{
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;

    /* Issue here */
    width:100%; 
    height:auto; 

    margin:0!important;
    padding:0!important; 
    display:block
}
```

The width and height is specified. Just remove them.

Comment: None of you seen the error in the img markup attributes ? Setting attribute 'width' or 'height' with an error value, the < img > will NOT apply proportions to image

Comment: @MilchePatern There is no error, specifying the `height` and `width` with `px` works fine.

Comment: ATOzTOA can you confirm your last comment about erroneous units in < img > markup ?

Comment: @MilchePatern I say `<img src="1.jpg" width="100px" height="200px" />` works.

Answer (score 4):

Remove this property from your css

```
.bd-flickr-item img{
/*width:100%; 
    height:auto; */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I can see why your images wouldn't be 192px X 192px!**

in your html markup from the javascript output

```
$output .= '<img src="'.$img_url.'" height="192px" width="192px" alt="'. $xml->channel->item[$i]->title .'" title="'. $xml->channel->item[$i]->title .'">';

-->    height="192px" width="192px"
```

replace with :

```
height="192" width="192"
```

**Why ?** The 'width' attribute does not have a valid value: It must be an integer, or an integer percentage.

After, remove width and height from this .css selector

```
.bd-flickr-item img {
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
    /*width:100%; */
    /*height:auto;*/
    margin:0!important;
    padding:0!important; 
    display:block
}
```